# For loop for selecting date range with the requirement to meet certain criteria

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, time-series

I have the following quarterly data. But there are some dates where there is no data. I want to create a for loop which iterates through the indexes and checks that if in the assets column the date is NaN. If yes, then create a new data frame containing the part of data frame where is no NaN and the loop breaks.

So for example, the loop starts, between 9/30/2018 and 9/30/2016 everything is OK, then in the next iteration there is NaN (6/30/2016) so I want to create a data frame containing the rows between 9/30/2018 and 9/30/2016 and the loop breaks.

Note: It has to be with some kind of iteration because I want to do it with many excels and for some excels the exact date where the NaN kicks in could be at different times.

```
date           assets   debt
9/30/2018   4193    1824
6/30/2018   4281    1929
3/31/2018   4149    1460
12/31/2017  4238    1404
9/30/2017   3804    1401
6/30/2017   3583    1437
3/31/2017   3404    1451
12/31/2016  3181    1445
9/30/2016   3622    1478
6/30/2016   NaN NaN
3/31/2016   NaN NaN
12/31/2015  2566    225
9/30/2015   NaN NaN
6/30/2015   NaN     NaN
3/31/2015   NaN NaN
12/31/2014  2917    342
```

Here is what I have tried to far:

```
for date in df.index:
   if df['assets'][df.index == date].empty == True:
       newdf = df[df.index > date]
       break
```

Comment: please post the sample data in your post so that we can paste it in to our IDE as opposed to an image, also it's bad `pandas` practice to do have brackets back to back i.e `][`

Comment: Added the data and thanks for the pandas suggestions. Learning by every day.

Comment: so what's the expected output? because each iteration will overwrite the previous iterations variable

Comment: In that case the expected output would be the new dataframe which contains the data between 9/30/2018 and 9/30/2016. So basically with the loop I want to chip the part of the dataframe which containt the data without the NaN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `numpy` method `isnan` to extract the index and then indexing to grab the rest.

```
idx = np.isnan(df.assets).idxmax() # this is one way

idx = df.assets.isna().idxmax() # this is another way

newdf = df.iloc[:idx]

         date  assets    debt
0   9/30/2018  4193.0  1824.0
1   6/30/2018  4281.0  1929.0
2   3/31/2018  4149.0  1460.0
3  12/31/2017  4238.0  1404.0
4   9/30/2017  3804.0  1401.0
5   6/30/2017  3583.0  1437.0
6   3/31/2017  3404.0  1451.0
7  12/31/2016  3181.0  1445.0
8   9/30/2016  3622.0  1478.0
```

Putting this in a loop when reading your files should be trivial.

Comment: It works! Thank you very much. It was a great help and a feedback that i have to learn a lot.